# how do I nest elements dynamically using XSLT?

Tags: xslt

I am trying to do an identity transformation. Here is an example of my source xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<text>
    <p id="542">This is a parapgraph</p>
    <p id="561">This is a first level bullet</p>
    <p id="561">This is a first level bullet</p>
    <p id="561">This is a first level bullet</p>
    <p id="561">This is a first level bullet</p>
    <p id="561">This is a first level bullet</p>
    <p id="542">This is a parapgraph</p>
    <p id="561">This is a first level bullet</p>
    <p id="562">This is a second level bullet</p>
    <p id="562">This is a second level bullet</p>
    <p id="561">This is a first level bullet</p>
    <p id="561">This is a first level bullet</p>
    <p id="542">This is a parapgraph</p>
    <p id="542">This is a parapgraph</p>
    <p id="560">This is a first ordered list</p>
    <p id="560">This is a first ordered list</p>
    <p id="560">This is a first ordered list</p>
    <p id="562">This is a second level bullet</p>
    <p id="562">This is a second level bullet</p>

</text>enter code here
```

I am looking for an output that looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<text>
    <p id="">This is a parapgraph</p>
    <ul>
    <li>This is a first level bullet</li>
    <li>This is a first level bullet</li>
    <li>This is a first level bullet</li>
    <li>This is a first level bullet</li>
    <li>This is a first level bullet</li>
    </ul>
    <p id="">This is a parapgraph</p>
    <ul>
    <li>This is a first level bullet
        <ul>
            <li>This is a second level bullet</li>
            <li>This is a second level bullet</li>
            <li>This is a second level bullet</li>
        </ul></li>
    <li>This is a first level bullet</li>
    <li>This is a first level bullet</li>
    </ul>
    <p id="">This is a parapgraph</p>
    <p id="">This is a parapgraph</p>
    <ol>
    <li>This is a first ordered list</li>
    <li>This is a first ordered list</li>
    <li>This is a first ordered list</li>
    <li>This is a first level bullet
        <ul>
            <li>This is a second level bullet</li>
            <li>This is a second level bullet</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>This is a first level bullet</li>
    </ol>
</text>
```

Could you please help me understand how that can be done? I am new to XSLT. I was looking for a tutorial that does something like this but could not find one.
My current XSLT looks like the following:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

    <xsl:output method="xml" standalone="no"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="topic">
        <book>
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="generate-id(.)"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>

        </book>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="body">
        <text>

                <xsl:apply-templates select="p[@id='542']"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="f-ul"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="s-ul"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="o-l"/>

        </text>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- all body text style to p tag> -->
    <xsl:template match="p[@id='542']">
        <p><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="f-ul">
    <xsl:if test="p[@id='561']">
        <ul>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:text></xsl:text>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="p[@id='561']"/>
        </ul>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="s-ul">
    <xsl:if test="p[@id='562']">
        <ul>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:text></xsl:text>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="p[@id='562']"/>
        </ul>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="o-l">
    <xsl:if test="p[@id='560']">
        <ol>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:text></xsl:text>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="p[@id='560']"/>
        </ol>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>



    <!-- all list number style to step tag> -->

    <xsl:template match="p[@id='560']">
        <li><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></li>
    </xsl:template>


    <!-- all list bullet style to li tag> -->

    <xsl:template match="p[@id='561']">
        <li><xsl:apply-templates select="node()" /></li>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- all list bullet 2 style to li tag> -->
    <xsl:template match="p[@id='562']">
        <li><xsl:apply-templates select="node()" /></li>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If you can help me find a solution or at least direct me to the correct resources, that will be much appreciated. Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Is there any logic to the `id` numbers, or are they arbitrary? IOW, can there be more levels beyond the two in your example?

Comment: Yes. id numbers indicate the style. For example, if it is 542, then apply body text which in this case is a <p> tag. If it is 561, apply a list item, which in this case is <li> which will be part of a <ul>. The source will always have a flat structure like the one I posted. Based on the sequence, I need to figure out their nesting. For example, if a list of <p id="561"> occurs after a para, then I need to apply a <ul> and move all the <p id=561> to the <ul> until I encounter another different style. My current xslt moves all <p id=561> to a <ul>. I want to  retain their sequence.

Comment: I am afraid that doesn't answer my question. You are giving more examples, I asked if there is some general logic. If there isn't, you'll have to write out specific instructions for every possible `id` number. -- P.S. This is going to be either difficult or very difficult; if you're new to XSLT, this is not a good project for you.

Comment: The id numbers are not arbitrary. They are fixed. They will always be the same numbers given the source. I know it is going to be difficult for a person like me. But let me see. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always difficult to work from examples and I am not sure the shown wanted result is consistent, I would suggest a two step transformation, the first identifies li items and sets up `ol/ul`, the second then makes sure any inner list is wrapped into the preceding `li`.

Here is an XSLT 3 (available with Saxon 9.8 or 9.9 for Java and .NET and within XML IDEs like oXygen or Stylus Studio, also implemented by Altova Raptor in their product lines since the 2017 releases) approach of the first step:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:param name="list-levels" as="map(xs:integer, xs:integer+)"
    select="map { 1 : (560, 561), 2: (562) }"/>

  <xsl:param name="list-map" as="map(xs:integer, xs:QName)"
    select="map { 560 : QName('', 'ol'), 561 : QName('', 'ul'), 562 : QName('', 'ul') }"/>

  <xsl:function name="mf:group" as="node()*">
      <xsl:param name="nodes" as="node()*"/>
      <xsl:param name="level" as="xs:integer"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="$nodes" group-adjacent="boolean(self::p[@id = $list-levels?($level to 6)])">
          <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                  <xsl:element name="{$list-map(xs:integer(@id))}">
                      <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(current-group(), $level + 1)"/>
                  </xsl:element>                  
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
              </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:template match="text">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(*, 1)"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p[@id = 542]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p[@id = $list-levels?*]">
      <li>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </li>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can set it working at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPzifoZ with the following result:

```
<text>
   <p>This is a parapgraph</p>
   <ul>
      <li>This is a first level bullet</li>
      <li>This is a first level bullet</li>
      <li>This is a first level bullet</li>
      <li>This is a first level bullet</li>
      <li>This is a first level bullet</li>
   </ul>
   <p>This is a parapgraph</p>
   <ul>
      <li>This is a first level bullet</li>
      <ul>
         <li>This is a second level bullet</li>
         <li>This is a second level bullet</li>
      </ul>
      <li>This is a first level bullet</li>
      <li>This is a first level bullet</li>
   </ul>
   <p>This is a parapgraph</p>
   <p>This is a parapgraph</p>
   <ol>
      <li>This is a first ordered list</li>
      <li>This is a first ordered list</li>
      <li>This is a first ordered list</li>
      <ul>
         <li>This is a second level bullet</li>
         <li>This is a second level bullet</li>
      </ul>
   </ol>
</text>
```

For the second step I have added a mode to handle the wrapping of nested `ul` or `ol`:

```
  <xsl:mode name="wrap" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="ul | ol" mode="wrap">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="li">
              <xsl:copy>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="node(), current-group() except ." mode="#current"/>
              </xsl:copy>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="mf:group(*, 1)" mode="wrap"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

Example at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPzifoZ/1 produces the output

```
<text>
   <p>This is a parapgraph</p>
   <ul>
      <li>This is a first level bullet</li>
      <li>This is a first level bullet</li>
      <li>This is a first level bullet</li>
      <li>This is a first level bullet</li>
      <li>This is a first level bullet</li>
   </ul>
   <p>This is a parapgraph</p>
   <ul>
      <li>This is a first level bullet<ul>
            <li>This is a second level bullet</li>
            <li>This is a second level bullet</li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li>This is a first level bullet</li>
      <li>This is a first level bullet</li>
   </ul>
   <p>This is a parapgraph</p>
   <p>This is a parapgraph</p>
   <ol>
      <li>This is a first ordered list</li>
      <li>This is a first ordered list</li>
      <li>This is a first ordered list<ul>
            <li>This is a second level bullet</li>
            <li>This is a second level bullet</li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ol>
</text>
```

Full code is

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:param name="list-levels" as="map(xs:integer, xs:integer+)"
    select="map { 1 : (560, 561), 2: (562) }"/>

  <xsl:param name="list-map" as="map(xs:integer, xs:QName)"
    select="map { 560 : QName('', 'ol'), 561 : QName('', 'ul'), 562 : QName('', 'ul') }"/>

  <xsl:function name="mf:group" as="node()*">
      <xsl:param name="nodes" as="node()*"/>
      <xsl:param name="level" as="xs:integer"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="$nodes" group-adjacent="boolean(self::p[@id = $list-levels?($level to 6)])">
          <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                  <xsl:element name="{$list-map(xs:integer(@id))}">
                      <xsl:sequence select="mf:group(current-group(), $level + 1)"/>
                  </xsl:element>                  
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
              </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:mode name="wrap" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="ul | ol" mode="wrap">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="li">
              <xsl:copy>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="node(), current-group() except ." mode="#current"/>
              </xsl:copy>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="mf:group(*, 1)" mode="wrap"/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p[@id = 542]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="p[@id = $list-levels?*]">
      <li>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </li>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Examples use XSLT 3 but the grouping would be the same in XSLT 2, only storing the mapping of `p` ids to element and list levels would need to be done in some XML structure instead of the XPath `map`s I have used above.

Restriction: in `$level to 6` I have chosen some maximum nesting level of six but it can of course be easily adjusted.

However, choosing some smarter representation like an array would allow us to avoid having to define a maximum level, so with `<xsl:param name="list-levels" as="array(xs:integer+)"  select="[ (560, 561), (562) ]"/>` and then `<xsl:for-each-group select="$nodes" group-adjacent="boolean(self::p[@id = array:subarray($list-levels, $level)])">`, as in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPzifoZ/2, there is no need to define a maximum level hardcoded into the XSLT.

Comment: @ Martin Honnen, thank you for taking the trouble and finding a solution for the problem I have posted. This is exactly what I wanted. Though the source that I have will be much more complex than the sample that I posted here, this specific problem was going to trouble me anyways. I am not sure if I understand everything in your code. I will spend time and go through each line and figure out what you are doing in the code. Thank you so much once again.

Comment: Note that such problems come up with various XML formats from office or similar tools and there are certainly some resources online like https://gitlab.coko.foundation/XSweet/XSweet/tree/master/applications/list-promote that are more refined than a quich answer on SO. So you might want to check whether your markup falls into a know category and check existing solutions to restructure/format them.

Comment: Taken a note of that. Will join it. Thank you.

Comment: slightly unrelated to this topic. If I want to retain the sequence in the source, what part of the XSLT should I be learning so that I can work towards that? Some a note tag can occur anywhere. Thank you.